# JavaScript WebSocket & PHP Socket

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I want to make a socket connection using JavaScript and PHP.
I use JS WebSocket and PHP Socket.
If I run PHP scripts locally on the server, then they communicate with each other and the connection occurs (screenshot [1](https://prnt.sc/P3s2oK97ALdd)).

After the script ends on the server, the socket is not immediately available (screenshot [2](https://prnt.sc/T9563Qgs-A4R)).

If I open a client script in a browser using WebSocket, then the response is fixed in an incomprehensible encoding and it is not constant in the text, the only thing you can see on it is only the domain name from which the request came (screenshot [3](https://prnt.sc/19FMryV2l0IU)).

Port: 3000, on 80 and 443, socket not pinged.

**Question:**
What is the reason for the response from the browser in an incomprehensible encoding and is it necessary to pre-prepare the header text in JS for the handshake? I read on this forum that only the protocol can be optionally specified in WebSocket([url], [protocol]).

Thanks in advance for your advice.

## *Examples*:

*Answer*:

```
 ▒▒▒▒▒2B▒~▒˼[▒▒p'▒w▒
▒%▒▒c▒/ e▒O▒&ߍ▒▒L▒}▒▒4▒▒W▒▒▒4▒▒.▒▒ ▒▒̨̩▒+▒/▒,▒0▒▒▒▒/5▒▒▒domain.name▒
                                                                                                                       ▒▒
 #                                                                                                                   3+)/▒ ▒~l▒se▒▒lxk▒aG?i▒i0
 ;m^eCG▒▒jI-+JJ
               ih2**▒
```

============================

*Server code*:

```
<?php
// set some variables
$url_site = 'domain.name';
$host = gethostbyname($url_site);
$port = getservbyname('https', 'tcp');
$port = 3000;

// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
$flag_handshake = false;
$client = null;
header("Content-Type:application/javascript; charset=utf-8");

// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");
echo serialize($socket)." socket_create...\n\n";

// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
echo serialize($socket)." socket_bind...\n\n";

// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 0) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
echo serialize($socket)." socket_listen...\n\n";
echo "Ready to receive on wss://$host:$port/ ...\n";

do {
    if (!$client) {
        // accept incoming connections
        // client another socket to handle communication
        $client = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
        echo "Client << $client >> has connected.\n";
    }

    $bytes =  @socket_recv($client, $data, 2048, 0);
    if ($flag_handshake == false) {
        if ((int)$bytes == 0)
            continue;
        print("Handshaking headers from client: ". mb_detect_encoding($data) ." - ". $data ."\n");
        echo $client ." -->>LEN<<-- ". $bytes;
        if (handshake($client, $data, $socket)) {
            $flag_handshake = true;
        }
    }
    elseif($flag_handshake == true) {
        if ($data != "") {
            $decoded_data = unmask($data);
            print("< ". $decoded_data ."\n");
            $response = strrev($decoded_data);
            socket_write($client, encode($response));
            print("> ". $response ."\n");
            socket_close($client);
            $client = null;
            $flag_handshake = false;
        }
    }
} while (true);

// close sockets
socket_close($client);
socket_close($socket);

function handshake($client, $headers, $socket) {
    print(" [ HEADER: " . $headers ." ] ");
    if (preg_match("/Sec-WebSocket-Version: (.*)\r\n/", $headers, $match)) {
        $version = $match[1];
                    //$version = 333;
    } else {
        print(" [ The client doesn't support WebSocket ] ");
        return false;
                    //$version = 111;
    }

    if ($version == 13) {
        // Extract header variables
        if (preg_match("/GET (.*) HTTP/", $headers, $match))
            $root = $match[1];
        if (preg_match("/Host: (.*)\r\n/", $headers, $match))
            $host = $match[1];
        if (preg_match("/Origin: (.*)\r\n/", $headers, $match))
            $origin = $match[1];
        if (preg_match("/Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n/", $headers, $match))
            $key = $match[1];

        $acceptKey = $key.'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11';
        $acceptKey = base64_encode(sha1($acceptKey, true));

        $upgrade = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n".
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $acceptKey".
            "\r\n\r\n";

        socket_write($client, $upgrade);
        return true;
    } else {
        print("WebSocket version 13 required (the client supports version {$version})");
        return false;
    }
}

function unmask($payload) {
    $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;

    if ($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 6);
    }

    $text = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i % 4];
    }
    return $text;
}

function encode($text) {
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if ($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)$header = pack('CCS', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
    $header = pack('CCN', $b1, 127, $length);

    return $header.$text;
}
?>
```

============================

*Client code*:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<script>
var socket = new WebSocket('wss://domain.name:3000/');

console.log('New socket ');
console.log(socket);
console.log('Let`s open ');
// Open the socket
socket.onopen = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    var msg = 'I am the client.';
    console.log('> ' + msg);
    // Send an initial message
    socket.send(msg);
    // Listen for messages
    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log('< ' + event.data);
    };

    // Listen for socket closes
    socket.onclose = function(event) {
        console.log('Client notified socket has closed', event);
    };

    // To close the socket....
    socket.close()
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    console.log(`[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`);
  } else {
    console.log('[close] Connection died');
  }
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};
</script>
<body>
<p>Please check the console log of your browser.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

============================

Answer (score 0):

Sockets seem complex. I just found https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets written in 2012 and got it to work with PHP 8.1 this week.

It seems to work well. Though I haven't really used it to send and receive yet other than tests. Was planning to have the login open a socket and wait for the email confirmation. I even built a way to check the processes for www-data and shell_exec(PHP -q the socket.php[see img below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVu48.png)) to keep the socket open)

May the holy force be with you!